# Accessing groups in Pandas lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe with a multiindex.  Level 0 is 'Strain' and level 1 is 'JGI library.'  Each 'Strain' has several 'JGI library' columns associated with it.  I would like to use a lambda function to apply a t-test to compare two different strains.  To troubleshoot, I have been taking one row of my dataframe using the .iloc[0] command.

```
row = pvalDf.iloc[0]
parent = 'LL1004'
child = 'LL345'
ttest_ind(row.groupby(level='Strain').get_group(parent), row.groupby(level='Strain').get_group(child))[1]
```

This works as expected.  Now I try to apply it to my whole dataframe

```
parent = 'LL1004'
child = 'LL345'
pvalDf = countsDf4.apply(lambda row: ttest_ind(row.groupby(level='Strain').get_group(parent), row.groupby(level='Strain').get_group(child))[1])
```

Now I get an error message saying, "ValueError: ('level name Strain is not the name of the index', 'occurred at index (LL1004, BCHAC)')"

'LL1004' is a 'Strain,' but Pandas doesn't seem to be aware of this.  It looks like maybe the multiindex was not passed to the lambda function correctly?  Is there a better way to troubleshoot lambda functions than using .iloc[0]?

I put a copy of my Jupyter notebook and an excel file with the countsDf4 dataframe on Github https://github.com/danolson1/pandas_ttest

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about, more simply:

```
pvalDf = countsDf4.apply(lambda row: ttest_ind(row[parent], row[child]), axis=1)
```

I've tested it on your notebook and it works.

Your problem is that [`DataFrame.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) by default applies the function to each *column*, not to each row. So, you need to specify the `axis=1` parameter to override the default behavior and apply the function row by row.

Also, there's no reason to use `row.groupby(level='Strain').get_group(x)` when you could simply index the group of columns by `row[x]`. :)

Comment: `axis=1` solved the problem.  And thanks for the other comment as well.